# what is the option in mysql 5.6.10 for reducing warnings on 'unsafe Statement' in error log file?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am getting a lot of "Statement is not safe to log in statement format."  warnings in Mysql 5.6.10 as BINLOG_FORMAT format is '**STATEMENT**' and i can't switch it to '**MIXED**' or '**ROW**'.

Also i can't use option to switch off warnings logging at global level during function or stored procedure use and this setting it not available at session level in Mysql 5.6.10

can't use following at any point

```
    SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 0
```

But there is a release note for Mysql 5.6.7 which mentions of reducing or suppression mechanism for these error but not specified how to use it or what is the system variable name.

Can anybody please guide where to set it and how to set it like with example?

Following is the Mysql 5.6.7 release note

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-7.html

Replication: Statements such as UPDATE ... WHERE primary_key_column = constant LIMIT 1 are flagged as unsafe for statement-based logging, despite the fact that such statements are actually safe. In cases where a great many such statements were run, this could lead to disk space becoming exhausted do to the number of such false warnings being logged. **To prevent this from happening, a warning suppression mechanism is introduced. This warning suppression acts as follows: Whenever the 50 most recent ER_BINLOG_UNSAFE_STATEMENT warnings have been generated more than 50 times in any 50-second period, warning suppression is enabled. When activated, this causes such warnings not to be written to the error log; instead, for each 50 warnings of this type, a note is written to the error log stating The last warning was repeated N times in last S seconds. This continues as long as the 50 most recent such warnings were issued in 50 seconds or less; once the number of warnings has decreased below this threshold, the warnings are once again logged normally.**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings), you can set `log-warnings=0`, but pay attention that it may suppress other warnings as well..

Comment: I can't use this option. any idea about Mysql 5.6.7 release note which mentions of warning suppression mechanism ?